# Spring cloud Camden.SR1 hystrix.stream hangs

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, hystrix

I am trying to enable a hystrix stream in a Spring Cloud service, using Camden.SR1 in a spring boot app.
I enable hystrix by having a compile-time dependency:

```
compile 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-hystrix'
```

and by adding a @EnableHystrix in the Application configuration.

The /mappings actuator shows the /hystrix.stream endpoint available but when I do a GET on it, the request hangs indefinitely.
I have tried the same using Brixton.SR6 (thus using Spring Boot 1.3) and the hystrix.stream endpoint works as expected.
Am I doing something wrong or is this a regression?

Comment: have you exercised a circuit breaker?

Comment: A simple app from http://start.spring.io showed me it is working.

Comment: Here's a fork of the eureka sample with the aforementioned changes: https://github.com/florind/eureka-aws
Hangs for me...

Comment: All you did was add `@EnableHystrix` there is no circuit to exercise anywhere, hence nothing in the stream.

Comment: Btw, reverting the sample to Brixton makes the endpoint responsive with a repeated 'ping' which is the behaviour I'd expect.

Answer (score 1):

This issue seems linked with the Hystrix issue described here: https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/issues/1117. The workaround detailed here solves it https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/issues/1117#issuecomment-192222569

/hystrix.stream becames available amongst the actuator endpoints (add spring-boot-starter-hateoas and browse to /actuator). Regardless of any hystrix-enabled functionality in this service, this advertised endpoint should not hang.